# Copying files with a wildcard from and to directories that have a wildcard

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I want to copy files with various names & extensions, from a directory whose name has a given root but may have a suffix, to a different directory.

A for-loop appears to work for the directory wildcard but seems to preclude a wildcard for the filename. Here is what I have in the batch file:

```
SET /P M= ENTER THE TEST #
MKDIR "S:\Photometric\Experimental\E%M%"
COPY "S:\Photometric\Approved\%M%*\*.*" "S:\Photometric\Experimental\E%M%*"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET source_dir=S:\Photometric\Approved
SET target_dir=S:\Photometric\Experimental\E

SET /P M= ENTER THE TEST #
FOR /D /R %%G IN ("%source_dir%") DO (
    SET "folder_name=%%G"
    ECHO !folder_name! | FINDSTR /R "%M%" >nul && CALL :get_folder_name
    ECHO !folder_name! | FINDSTR /B /R "%M%" >nul && ROBOCOPY "%source_dir%\!folder_name!" "%target_dir%\!folder_name!" /S
)


ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO Done^^!
PAUSE
EXIT


:get_folder_name
SET folder_name=!folder_name:*\%M%=%M%!

SET endbit=!folder_name:*\=!
SET folder_name=!folder_name:%endbit%=!
SET folder_name=!folder_name:~0,-1!
EXIT /B
```

This will search through the `source_dir` and copy every file and sub-folder of each folder which matches `%M%` to the `target_dir`.

This is probably not the most effective way to achieve this, but as the `/XD` option of `ROBOCOPY` does not work with wildcards I could not think of any better.